# ASCII char set in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, ascii

The problem is in cracking code Interview: implement an algorithm to determine if a string has all unique characters. And here is the solution:

```
public class ASCII {
public static boolean isUnique (String str) {
    boolean[] charSet = new boolean[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int val = str.charAt(i);
        if (charSet[val]) {
            return false;
        }
        charSet[val] = true;
    }
    return true;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] words = {"abcde", "hello"};
    for (String word : words) {
        System.out.println(word + ":" + isUnique(word));
    }
}
}
```

I have a very basic question that why creating the charSet with the length 256? Because based on ASCII chart, (http://www.techonthenet.com/ascii/chart.php), I was thinking we need only 127 numbers to express all the characters. Thanks!

Comment: Off by one! Goddam! It's 128!

Comment: so it should be 128 instead of 256? @Ingo

Comment: Yes, but only when you are absolutly sure that there are only ASCII characters in the String. There is no reason to restrict yourself to ASCII characters. Just make a `new boolean[0x10000]`, so you can safely index any character.

Comment: Who is "we"?  I didn't create the `charSet`.  After you use `charAt`, `val` can actually be in the range `0` to `65535`, because we have Unicode now.  So the question is, how do you know whether the argument passed to the program will have all ASCII characters?

Comment: If the question really is "*determine if a string has all unique characters.*" you should be using a `boolean[Character.MAX_VALUE]`...

Comment: @assylias Off by one, again. You need Character.MAX_VALUE+1

Answer (score 4):

Because there's extended ASCII

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII

The 128-255 codes encode culture specific chars.

And if you want to account for all Unicode values, you should do:

```
boolean[] charSet = new boolean[Character.MAX_VALUE + 1];
```

instead of what you currently do.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is incorrect. Java String may use 65536 characters. The interview question does not say about ASCII

Comment: so for the line 3 `boolean[] charSet = new boolean[256]`, should I create the charSet as `boolean[] charSet = new boolean[65536];` ? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this question as well and had the same question. Here is the solution

```
    if (str.length() > 128) {
        return false;
    }

    boolean[] char_set = new boolean[128];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int val = str.charAt(i);
        if (char_set[val]) return false;
        char_set[val] = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```